# Some user from some networks cannot connect to my webserver... and I cannot understand why

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

After a huge ddos attack we move our webserver behind a CDN.
Now we are returning to the original situation, and we have an issue: some user cannot access to the website.

One of my collaborator can access to the website only with his 4G connection, not with the dsl. Same for some companies... a very very small percentage.

We cannot find the issue, it's very strange. Our provider tell us that they don't have any firewall on filter, our webserver is not behind a firewall. We use nginx but looks like user are stopped before nginx...

Any idea? 
We are trying several trace-route, it's something that also the provider cannot understand. The tell us that is our server, but I don't have nothing on my server that can block only several connection.

I add more info:

- my collaborator can accesso to the server using ssh, so is not a route problem.
- I try to regenerate https certificates, nothing change

Here is the firewall log of my server where 212.78.6.2 is the webserver ip and 77.242.191.40 my collaborator ip address

```
 26.056137   212.78.6.2 -> 77.242.191.40 TLSv1.2 [TCP Retransmission] Server Hello, 
 26.472648 77.242.191.40 -> 212.78.6.2   TCP 14089 > 443 [RST, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=2058 Len=0
 61.549905 77.242.191.40 -> 212.78.6.2   TCP 14093 > 443 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=65535 Len=0 MSS=1460 WS=6 TSV=906321074 TSER=0
 61.550209   212.78.6.2 -> 77.242.191.40 TCP 443 > 14093 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=28960 Len=0 MSS=1460 TSV=1758904297 TSER=906321074 WS=7
 61.572694 77.242.191.40 -> 212.78.6.2   TCP 14093 > 443 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=131712 Len=0 TSV=906321098 TSER=1758904297
 61.572793 77.242.191.40 -> 212.78.6.2   SSL Client Hello
 61.572996   212.78.6.2 -> 77.242.191.40 TCP 443 > 14093 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=518 Win=30080 Len=0 TSV=1758904303 TSER=906321098
 61.577147   212.78.6.2 -> 77.242.191.40 TLSv1.2 Server Hello, Certificate, 
 61.577166   212.78.6.2 -> 77.242.191.40 TLSv1.2 Encrypted Handshake Message, Server Key Exchange, Server Hello Done
 61.597452 77.242.191.40 -> 212.78.6.2   TCP [TCP Dup ACK 35#1] 14093 > 443 [ACK] Seq=518 Ack=1 Win=131712 Len=0 TSV=906321125 TSER=1758904303 SLE=2897 SRE=3557
 61.604023   212.78.6.2 -> 77.242.191.40 TLSv1.2 [TCP Retransmission] Server Hello, 
 61.604042   212.78.6.2 -> 77.242.191.40 TLSv1.2 [TCP Retransmission] Certificate, 
 61.828018   212.78.6.2 -> 77.242.191.40 TLSv1.2 [TCP Retransmission] Server Hello, 
 62.276016   212.78.6.2 -> 77.242.191.40 TLSv1.2 [TCP Retransmission] Server Hello, 
 63.172024   212.78.6.2 -> 77.242.191.40 TLSv1.2 [TCP Retransmission] Server Hello, 
 64.968028   212.78.6.2 -> 77.242.191.40 TLSv1.2 [TCP Retransmission] Server Hello, 
 68.559970   212.78.6.2 -> 77.242.191.40 TLSv1.2 [TCP Retransmission] Server Hello, 
 75.752100   212.78.6.2 -> 77.242.191.40 TLSv1.2 [TCP Retransmission] Server Hello, 
 90.120075   212.78.6.2 -> 77.242.191.40 TLSv1.2 [TCP Retransmission] Server Hello, 
 91.577866 77.242.191.40 -> 212.78.6.2   TCP 14093 > 443 [RST, ACK] Seq=518 Ack=1 Win=131712 Len=0
 94.740099 77.242.191.40 -> 212.78.6.2   TCP 13967 > 443 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=65535 Len=0 MSS=1460 WS=6 TSV=906354101 TSER=0
 94.740388   212.78.6.2 -> 77.242.191.40 TCP 443 > 13967 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=28960 Len=0 MSS=1460 TSV=1758912595 TSER=906354101 WS=7
 94.757051 77.242.191.40 -> 212.78.6.2   TCP 13967 > 443 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=131712 Len=0 TSV=906354123 TSER=1758912595
 94.757262 77.242.191.40 -> 212.78.6.2   SSL Client Hello
 94.757435   212.78.6.2 -> 77.242.191.40 TCP 443 > 13967 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=518 Win=30080 Len=0 TSV=1758912599 TSER=906354123
 94.761625   212.78.6.2 -> 77.242.191.40 TLSv1.2 Server Hello, Certificate, 
 94.761641   212.78.6.2 -> 77.242.191.40 TLSv1.2 Encrypted Handshake Message, Server Key Exchange, Server Hello Done
 94.785478 77.242.191.40 -> 212.78.6.2   TCP [TCP Dup ACK 53#1] 13967 > 443 [ACK] Seq=518 Ack=1 Win=131712 Len=0 TSV=906354148 TSER=1758912599 SLE=2897 SRE=3557
 94.791994   212.78.6.2 -> 77.242.191.40 TLSv1.2 [TCP Retransmission] Server Hello, 
 94.792006   212.78.6.2 -> 77.242.191.40 TLSv1.2 [TCP Retransmission] Certificate, 
 95.012048   212.78.6.2 -> 77.242.191.40 TLSv1.2 [TCP Retransmission] Server Hello, 
 95.452044   212.78.6.2 -> 77.242.191.40 TLSv1.2 [TCP Retransmission] Server Hello, 
 96.332024   212.78.6.2 -> 77.242.191.40 TLSv1.2 [TCP Retransmission] Server Hello,
```

Comment: Do traceroutes and talk to the ISPs and CDN. I would certainly need more information in order to help you out.

Comment: I would start with getting the output of `mtr -r -n -c2 example.com` from affected parties. Without data allanone can do is guess.

Comment: @Tommiie i added some info